# Store object in a tree gives segmentation fault (c++)

Tags: c++, tree, nodes, fault

I have a serious problem and couldn't find an answer anywhere. I hope someone is able to help me here.

First of all I try to create an array Tree with information stored in

Node.h file

```
class Node {
public:
 Node();
 void setPerson(Person* _p) {
 this->person = _p;
 }

Node* getNode(int i) { return nodes[i];}
void insert(Person* _p, Tele* _tele, int i);
private:
 Node *nodes[10];
 Person* person;
};
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node() { 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { nodes[i] = new Node(); } 
    person = new Person(); 
}

void Node::insert(Person* _p, Tele _tele, int i) {
      std::string t=tele.getString();
      if(t.size()==i) {
         this->person = _p;   // here comes the segmentation fault
       } else {
       char charNode t.at(i);
       int nextNode = charNode - '0';
       nodes[nextNode]->insert(_p,_tele,++i);
       }
   }
```

Comment: What does the constructor of `Node()` do? and particularly, how do you tread the member `Node *nodes[10]`?

Comment: The constructor initiate the new nodes and a new person object;

Comment: My crystal ball believes you haven't allocated all the `Node`s in the array yet.

Comment: `Node::Node() {
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    nodes[i] = new Node();
  }
  person = new Person();
}`

Answer (score 2):

Before you even attempt `insert`, the constructor constructs 10 nodes on the heap... each of which constructs 10 more nodes... each of which constructs 10 more nodes...

I think the trouble is that your computer doesn't have enough memory. Try constructing a ***finite*** tree instead.

Comment: yeah i came to the same solution but how should i do it? i want to stay with the recursion.

Comment: Erm, allocate lazily?

Comment: yeah, thx for the tip its working!! 
I implemented a static variable which counted to 20 (dosnt need more nodes) and now the error is gone.